# Chrome Extension won't get URL on the first try

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have a Google Chrome extension with a popup.html page.

The only script that starts when the page loads is:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    window.domain = "";
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(function (tabs) {
      window.domain = tabs.url;
      console.log(window.domain);
    });
    window.enabled = true;
    domain = window.domain;
    checkStatus();

});
```

the function checkStatus is:

```
function checkStatus() {
  if (enabled === true) {
    $(".status").html("Enabled");
    $(".statusContainer").css("background-color", "rgb(24, 150, 71)");
    $(".powerButton").attr("src", "images/enabled.png");
    $(".questionContainer").show("fast");
    $(".domain").html("on " + window.domain);
  }
  else if (enabled === false){
    $(".status").html("Disabled");
    $(".statusContainer").css("background-color", "rgb(102, 102, 102)");
    $(".powerButton").attr("src", "images/disabled.png");
    $(".questionContainer").hide("fast");
  }
}
```

however, when I click on the extension's icon to open the page, I only see "on " instead of "on google.com," for example. When I inspect popup and switch to console and run checkStatus again, however, the extension shows "on google.com," if I am on google, for example.

I'm not sure what is causing this, but the console.log shows the url as it should, so I think it's a problem with the checkStatus function, since the tab is loaded when I open the popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical issue of asynchronism

The callback part of `chrome.tabs.getSelected` will most probably be called **after** you called `checkStatus()`, which will result in `window.domain` still being the empty string `""`

Solution: You should call `checkStatus()` from inside the callback

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    window.domain = "";
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(function (tabs) {
      window.domain = tabs.url;
      console.log(window.domain);
      window.enabled = true;
      domain = window.domain;
      checkStatus();
    });

});
```